# Failure connecting to a CyberArk managed server using MacOS

Tags: mac-osx, rdp

My company has recently implemented CyberArk (10.6.0.23) to manage and control the remote access to the servers.

I have no issues accessing the servers using a Windows 10 PC, however, when using MacOS (in my case Mojave) I'm getting issues after downloading the RDP file and trying to connect via Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mac (Version 10.2.11 [1585]).

It pops up the window asking for the credentials and after that, it got hung and shows the following message:

*[We couldn't connect to the remote PC. You might not have permission to sign in remotely. Contact your network administrator for assistance. Error code: 0x9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8ECl.png)*

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution for this problem.

Basically, Microsoft RDP Client version 10 does not support connecting without NLA, since it ignores the value of the parameter EnableCredSspSupport.
This means that PSM sessions with PVWA will not be successful with RDP Client version 10.

Try the following steps to get it sorted:

1. Use Microsoft RDP Client for Mac starting from version 10.2.2
2. Run the following command on the Mac Terminal

```
defaults write com.microsoft.rdc.macos ClientSettings.EnforceCredSSPSupport 0
```

3. Close terminal and try to connect